# Cannot associate Asset to Campaign - REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am seeing a general error when trying to posting an Asset to a Campaign (Create a CampaignAsset). The post ability was working about 1 week ago. Even the SDK examples from FuelSDK-CSharp no longer work when trying to post an Asset to a Campaign.

> Error: {"message":"A general error occurred while trying to associate
>   assets","errorcode":10000,"documentation":""}

Is anyone else seeing the same issue?

Comment: I believe this is a known issue that the SFMC development team is working on.  Believe there should be a fix pushing out in mid-April to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have encountered the same issued since last week. Have you figured out how to solve it?

Comment: guys, wouldn't you agree that the first part of this question does answer the main question above ? It confirms that OP is not the only one with this issue, and that it may be broader than his own implementation/customization.