# Cannot associate email asset with campaign using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm new to the Marketing Cloud API and have run into a problem in trying to associate an email asset with a campaign using the endpoint

```
/hub/v1/campaigns/{campaignID}/assets
```

as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/associateAssetToCampaign.htm

The specific error is:

```
Error code: 10000
Message: A general error occurred while trying to associate assets
HTTP status code: 400
```

I created the campaign manually by logging into the SFMC console. The email asset itself was created via API using:

```
/asset/v1/content/assets
```

The type of email is "htmlemail" (type ID 208).

My payload to associate the email with the campaign is:

```
{
"ids": ["42886"],
"type": "EMAIL"
}
```

...where 42886 is the email asset ID.

When I log into the console and manually associate the email with the campaign, and then (as a GET call) use

```
/hub/v1/campaigns/{CampaignID}/assets
```

to retrieve all the assets in my campaign, I notice that the type is "CMS_ASSET", so I also tried using "CMS_ASSET" as the type in my call to associate the email with the campaign (using a new, unassociated email) but received the same error.

I also tried "htmlemail" as the type.

Note: This problem has the same symptoms as an unresolved question from three years ago ([Cannot associate Asset to Campaign - REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69192/cannot-associate-asset-to-campaign-rest-api)), although that one was described as a new problem that occurred in a previously working integration.

Many thanks in advance for any help anyone might be able to offer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was the installed package didn't have the correct permission to write campaigns. Once the permission was fixed, the call worked.